# how to merge master into branch in github for windows?

Tags: windows, git, github

I am new to github and try to merge master branch into my branch then commit my work ,how I can do that using github for windows .

Comment: Do you want to merge master to a local or a remote branch?

Comment: Reviewers (close votes), please note that programming tools are ON topic for Stack Overflow. Github is a legitimate and common programming tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open terminal cd to your local root

git add . 
git commit -m "your commit"
git push

This will move all of your local changes to master

*If you are working with someone else that has updated code you will need to do a git pull before the push

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to do a merge for a local branch use http://www.wdtutorials.com/drupal-7/github-windows-tutorial-3-branching-local-merging#.VYsBlRNVhBc

This is a pretty good github source for beginners.
http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/

Comment: Did Odai say anything about pull requests?

Comment: You are right I posted the wrong thing I don't have comment capability on his post, and i wasn't quite sure what he was looking for. Thank you for the question.